# How does lock free hashtable actually work

Tags: multithreading, hashmap, locking, concurrenthashmap

I went through http://preshing.com/20130529/a-lock-free-linear-search/
and https://code.google.com/p/nbds/

I can't understand how any of these hashtable are lock fee. I mean if we have two methods on a hashtable getItem and setItem. And this is my function

```
function increment2(key):
    val = hashtable.getItem(key) + 2
    hashtable.setItem(val)
```

Now this function runs in 2 threads, now if I don't use a lock in this function value of hashtable.getItem(key) can be increased by 2 or 4. 
I am very confused can someone help me in understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talk about *concurrent containers*, we usually mean that **single operation**, defined for this container, **is atomic**. In your case `hashtable.getItem(key)` and `hashtable.setItem(key, val)` are *atomic* operations. E.g. if `.getItem()` is executed concurrently with `.setItem()`, then it will return either new value or old value, but not a mix of them.

But concurrent container **doesn't garantee, that *sequence*** of two or more its operations **is atomic**. If user needs atomic property for sequence of operations, he shouldn't expect this property from container's implementation but  implement this property by hands. In your case, if you need `increment2` function to be *atomic*, you need to implement this property by yourself.

**Lock-based concurrent containers usually can be easy modified** for make some sequence of operations to be atomic.

From the other side, **lock-free concurrent containers hardly can be extended** to have sequence of the operations to be atomic. Lock-free algorithms are very  fragile in that sence.